# Help with drawing a polygon with N sides

Tags: 2d, algorithm, geometry

***I am at university on my games development, and I have been given work to fill in an empty pixel plotter program using the methods they have supplied for it to teach us the algorithms used in 2 dimensional games.***

I am currently trying to draw a polygon of N Sides using a function called void `PixelPlotterForm::DrawPolygon( int Sides, int X, int Y, int R, Color PixelColour )`
which we have been given the parameter but not the algorithm.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
void PixelPlotterForm::DrawPolygon( int Sides, int X, int Y, int R, Color PixelColour )
{
    // Fill in the correct code here
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    //float currentr = 360 / Sides;
    int n = 0;
    int r = R;
    for (n = 0; n < Sides; n++)
    {
        x = r * cos(2 * PI*n / Sides) + X;
        y = r * sin(2 * PI* n / Sides) + Y;
        SetViewportPixel(x, y, PixelColour); // this is where the function is called
      // and the pixel is set from this. 
    }

}
```

Currently the code does not work as desired, at the moment I have only reached drawing all 4 points, but something when drawing the polygon makes the points go skew-wif so to speak.

The left image is the trace that is drawn as a bounding box from the mouse, dragging it makes it larger like any image editing software, but the result is on the right, seems to set the angle off somehow, not sure why as the point should correlate to the trace.
[image: OUTCOME IMAGE] <<-- This image shows the actual result.

**I am also of course required to draw the outline of the polygon, so I assume that I should store in a cycle of points to create a triangle so I can draw the hypotenuse, but I am unsure how to do this.**

Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: unfortunately the code for the trace is hidden, I've searched the whole program so I don't unfortunately know how that works.

Comment: Why are you adding `R` to your angles?

Comment: @kolrabi Not sure, Think thats a mistake, still has a similar outcome on removal though.

Comment: @kolrabi nevermind fixed that problem, now I just have the difficulty of drawing from point to point.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend showing this sort of stuff from a Uni course, it's not fair to the creator. Asking about the theory would be more ethical in my opinion.

Comment: The university is ok with it, and so is the lecturer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you also had problems drawing a line from point to point. I recommend you look into "Bresenham's Line Algorithm" as it typically gives the best result. Here is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) about it.

The article includes pseudocode for the algorithm, including one that only relies on integer arithmetic. I won't be posting it here as I encourage you to actually read it. Once you have it working it should only be a matter of cycling through the points drawing lines between them. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I'm sitting here wondering if this is really a gamedev related question to begin with.

Comment: I thought it was because in the next worksheet we apply these principles to drawing pixels in a 2dimensional game, sorry I should have made it more clear.

Comment: @NilsOleTimm If it makes you feel any better, I think game-programmers have more knowlege about graphics and graphics algorithms than your standard web-developer, system maintainer or what have you. So I don't blame him for posting here. I go by the test of "Would a game-programmer know more about this than your average programmer?".

Comment: I go by the same test, so I guess we have a different perspective then. I think any programmer can easily solve that issue.

Comment: @Christer funnily enough , I have already used Bresenhams line algorithm, for the line function, I did not think of it thats such a simple answer. 

I obviously overcomplicated it in my head.

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting the angles properly, the sum of the internal angle of a simple polygon can be calculated with the formula: *π(n-2)*.

We then need the external angle which is the angle from point to point, this can be calculated with : *π-internalAngle*.

Assuming the first point is in the lower left and there's no rotation this code should work.

```
void PixelPlotterForm::DrawPolygon( int Sides, int X, int Y, int R, Color PixelColour )
        {
            // Fill in the correct code here
            int x = X;
            int y = Y;
            internalAngle = PI * (Sides-2) / Sides;
            externalAngle = PI - internalAngle
            for (int n = 0; n < Sides; n++)
            {
                x += R * cos(externalAngle * n);
                y += R * sin(externalAngle * n);
                SetViewportPixel(x, y, PixelColour); // this is where the function is called
              // and the pixel is set from this. 
            }
         }
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, it offsets the polygon and then misses the first point.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/4241d2a63b55c10ad5a0eb299e493746.png << heres an image of the outcome.

Comment: Made a mistake, have edited.

Comment: Seems not to work again, maybe there is a discrepancy in the function parameters I need to correct ?  https://i.gyazo.com/2a2bc409d87d8bcddf9bfaed74ab3624.png << image outcome

Comment: Ahhhh, I figured out the mistake, sorry the first point is always the top point, and the coordinates work downwards, as the Y coordinates actually start 0 at the top. I should have clarified that @Tim